# Vuejs does not update my interface, anyone know why?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I have an app with vuejs. I have an object that is being updated from an API every 10 seconds, it must also change the Html (interface) when it's updated.

I am getting some difficulties in updating the interface although I can see the object changing in the console, therefore I know its changing.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
watch: {
  myObj() {
    for (let [key, tuner] of Object.entries(myObj)) {
    ---- some code ----
     }
  }
 },
},
created() {
 setInterval(this.callMyApi(), 10000);
},
```

I call my API every 10 seconds and then i use the WATCH property to check when myObj changes and the do some logic with it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! By the way, your code `setInterval(this.callMyApi(), 10000);` should actually be `this.callMyApi(); setInterval(this.callMyApi(), 10000);` so you call the function right away and for each 10 sec after that, or you will only have data after 10 sec passed... 

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 components to this that are extremely important to ensure that watching an object -- especially with nested properties -- works correctly.

First, you must either A) instantiate the property as an object by declaring `myObj: {}` or B) use `Vue.set(this, 'myObj', yourCustomObject)` to ensure that it is reactive.

Second, you must use `deep: true`, if your object contains nested objects/arrays.

```
watch: {
  myObj: {
    deep: true, // this is the important part

    handler() {
      // your code
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Vue.set always gives me an error dont know why